# Как сделать, чтоб через один layout был виден другой

Tags: android, layout

Как сделать это через xml. Пытался делать через alpha, background не помогает.

```
    <LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:alpha="0.3"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="2" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: По умолчанию вьюхи прозрачны. Т.е. то, что вам нужно - суть поведение по умолчанию. Чтобы понять почему у вас это не работает -
 покажите вашу разметку

Comment: Нужно чтобы через FrameLayout был виден LinearLayout

Comment: Попробуйте убрать android:alpha="0.3" у Frame. И поставьте какой-то фон для Linear. Должно быть всё видно

Comment: Параметр alpha - убрал. В качестве фона LinearLayout стоит View. Всё равно не видно её.

Comment: Если параметр visibility у frame2 поставить gone, то View становится видна. Но тогда не виден frame2.

Comment: Фоном надо атрибут сделать а не вьюху. Так она у вас просто в экран не влезает

Comment: А поверх вьюхи прозрачный фрейм сделать нельзя?

Comment: Можно, но тогда вам надо корневым `FrameLayout` сделать.

Comment: Да. Так получилось. Странно, что через `LinearLayout` не вышло. Спасибо)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам надо корневой элемент сделать `FrameLayout` вместо `LinearLayout`, т.к. вам надо, чтобы вьюхи внутри располагались одна над другой по оси Z вместо расположения подряд по вертикали, из-за чего у вас вьха с фоном не влезала в экран или вытесняла вьюху с контентом.

Во `FrameLayout` же они обе умещаются в экран, размещаясь одна над другой.